# Iteration in k means clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am implementing k means clustering in tensorflow and have successfully made the function where we randomly select centroids from the sample points. Then these centroids are to be updated based on distance from sample points.

Is it always guaranteed that the more i iterate the better I get the cluster prediction or there is some point after which the predictions start getting wrong/anomalous??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing convergence in k means clustering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924630/implementing-convergence-in-k-means-clustering)

Comment: If I get a good prediction with 10 iterations will the prediction improve after 100 iterations... Is it guaranteed?

Comment: Hey, see this. https://github.com/imrealashu/kmean_fcm/ you'll get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, K-means solving algorithm behaves as expected, in that it converges to a *local* minimum always. (I assume you're talking about the Lloyd/Florgy method) This is a statistical method used to find a local minima. It may stall at a saddle point where one of the dimensions is optimized but the others is not.

[image]

To abbreviate the rigorousness of the proof, it will always converge, albeit slowly due to many saddle points in your function.

There is no point in which your prediction gets more "wrong". It will be closer to the minima that you wanted, but the minima may not be the *global*. This may be your source of concern, because random initializations of K-means does not guarrantee this to happen.

One way to alleviate this is to actually run K-means on subgroups of your data, and then take those final points and average them to find a good initializer for your final clustering on the whole dataset.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The may be **real local minima**, too. You could get out of saddle points with random shifts. But I don't think it is common for k-means to get stuck in a saddle point.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you're right, but the original impl of kmeans doesn't add noise to the shift. Also, it's not common but I've seen it get stuck for a couple iterations before it diverges on either side of the saddle point. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the optimization function can have saddle points at all; and because this is **not a gradient based solver** saddle points are not that important IMHO.

Comment: Fair enough about the gradient based solver point, but I believe the K-means function is non-convex, since the hessian is not always positive semi-def, so there definitely exists saddle points.